# How to set scrollbar thumb programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, scrollbar

I know listview can set scrollbar thumb in XML like this `Android:scrollbarThumbVertical` etc.

But I'm creating a listview instance in the java code and I maybe need to set different scrollbar thumb. Is there a method can set scrollbar thumb programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know the answer to this, but after a bit of digging around I don't think it's possible without a load of hassle.

This xml attribute is actually associated with a `View`, not a `ListView` - In the Android View source code, it seems that the only place that it is setting the vertical thumb drawable is the ['initializeScrollbars'](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#L3259) method.  Now this method isn't private, so we can extend any child of View and override this method, but the issue is that a crucial component needed to set the thumb drawable, the ScrollabilityCache, is private without any getter methods.

So without rewriting a lot of the code I don't think there's any easy way to do this - sorry!

Answer (score 26):

You can achieve that via reflection:

```
try
{
    Field mScrollCacheField = View.class.getDeclaredField("mScrollCache");
    mScrollCacheField.setAccessible(true);
    Object mScrollCache = mScrollCacheField.get(listview);
    Field scrollBarField = mScrollCache.getClass().getDeclaredField("scrollBar");
    scrollBarField.setAccessible(true);
    Object scrollBar = scrollBarField.get(mScrollCache);
    Method method = scrollBar.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setVerticalThumbDrawable", Drawable.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(scrollBar, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.scrollbar_style));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above code executes as:

```
listview.mScrollCache.scrollBar.setVerticalThumbDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.scrollbar_style));
```

Comment: Hi, @Eng.Fouad above solution  is not working in recyclerview..even /*listview.mScrollCache.scrollBar.setVerticalThumbDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.scrollbar_style))*/  this line is not working with listview or recyclerview.

Comment: Triggers an error on API 29: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.widget.ScrollBarDrawable.setVerticalThumbDrawable [class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable]`

Comment: for API 29, we can just call setVerticalScrollbarThumbDrawable(drawable)

Answer (score 3):

I modified the answer to make it a method 100% programmatically

```
public static void ChangeColorScrollBar(View Scroll, int Color, Context cxt){
   try
   {
       Field mScrollCacheField = View.class.getDeclaredField("mScrollCache");
       mScrollCacheField.setAccessible(true);
       Object mScrollCache = mScrollCacheField.get(Scroll);
       Field scrollBarField = mScrollCache.getClass().getDeclaredField("scrollBar");
       scrollBarField.setAccessible(true);
       Object scrollBar = scrollBarField.get(mScrollCache);
       Method method = scrollBar.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setVerticalThumbDrawable", Drawable.class);
       method.setAccessible(true);

       Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[1];
       ShapeDrawable sd1 = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
       sd1.getPaint().setColor(cxt.getResources().getColor(Color));
       sd1.setIntrinsicWidth(Math.round(cxt.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dp_3)));
       layers[0] = sd1;

       method.invoke(scrollBar, layers);
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android Q (API level 29), you can use [`setVerticalScrollbarThumbDrawable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setVerticalScrollbarThumbDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) & [`setHorizontalScrollbarThumbDrawable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setHorizontalScrollbarThumbDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)):

```
scrollView.verticalScrollbarThumbDrawable = 
                       ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources,     
                       R.drawable.scrollview_thumb, null)
```