# Change the Color of ScrollView Programmatically

Tags: android, android-xml, android-scrollview

### What I'm currently doing

Currently, I have changed the scrollbar in my XML file using the [`android:scrollbarThumbVertical`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbarThumbVertical) property like so:

```xml
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_blue"
    ... >
```

And `scrollbar_blue` refers to my `scrollbar_blue.xml` file, which is this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:centerColor="@color/blue"
        android:endColor="@color/blue"
        android:startColor="@color/blue" />

    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

---

### What I want to do

I have a colour option for my app - so when the colour is on, it should stay blue; otherwise, it should be grey.

**How can I programmatically (in my activity class) change my ScrollView to use my `scrollbar_grey.xml`**?

If you look at the Android documentation on [`ScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html), there is no corresponding method to `android:scrollbarThumbVertical`

I'm fine with another way change the colour as well.

Here is how I create the reference to my ScrollView:

```java
ScrollView scr = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
```

Comment: try this 
scr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourstylexml)

Comment: @mohammedmomn That doesn't change the colour of the *scrollbar*, it changes the colour of the entire *scrollview*. Thanks for trying something though.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a method to change it programmatically but that method is not exposed. There doesn't seem to be anything else to change it programmatically from what I have read.

However, I did come across this one stackoverflow answer that uses reflection to do it.
Please upvote the answer there if it works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19819843/3286163

The answer was for a listview but is the same for the scrollview:

```
ScrollView scr = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
try
{
    Field mScrollCacheField = View.class.getDeclaredField("mScrollCache");
    mScrollCacheField.setAccessible(true);
    Object mScrollCache = mScrollCacheField.get(scr); // scr is your Scroll View

    Field scrollBarField = mScrollCache.getClass().getDeclaredField("scrollBar");
    scrollBarField.setAccessible(true);
    Object scrollBar = scrollBarField.get(mScrollCache);

    Method method = scrollBar.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setVerticalThumbDrawable", Drawable.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);

    // Set your drawable here.
    method.invoke(scrollBar, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.scrollbar_blue));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Only thing I could find. I gave it a try myself and it worked.

Comment: Great answer (especially with source)! Side note: pretty ridiculous that Android doesn't have an explicit method for this.

Answer (score 1):

In API 29+ use `ScrollView.setVerticalScrollbarThumbDrawable()` otherwise use the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy nowadays :)

```
scrollView.verticalScrollbarThumbDrawable = ColorDrawable(Color.CYAN)
scrollView.horizontalScrollbarThumbDrawable = ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE)
```

Comment: Yes and It requires minimum API 29

Answer (score 0):

This method requires **API 29** and higher :

```
public static void changeBarColor(ScrollView sv, int thumbColor,int trackColor) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        sv.getVerticalScrollbarThumbDrawable().setTint(thumbColor);
        sv.getVerticalScrollbarTrackDrawable().setTint(trackColor);
    }
}
```

[image]