# Change color of scrollbar programmatically

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, scrollbar, scrollview

How can I change color of my scroll bar programmatically?

```
ScrollView scrollView1 = new ScrollView(context);
scrollView1.LayoutParameters = lparams;
scrollView1.LayoutParameters.Height = chartHeight;
scrollView1.LayoutParameters.Width = scrollWidth;
```

I want to create TRANSPARENT scroll bar.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806852/change-the-color-of-scrollview-programmatically

Comment: I use Xamarin Android (C# code), not Java

Comment: This guy wanted to change the speed of the scroll bar. http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/20938/#Comment_20938
Seems you will need to create a customer ScrollView Control

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via reflection:

```
try
{
    Field mScrollCacheField = View.class.getDeclaredField("mScrollCache");
    mScrollCacheField.setAccessible(true);
    Object mScrollCache = mScrollCacheField.get(listview);
    Field scrollBarField = mScrollCache.getClass().getDeclaredField("scrollBar");
    scrollBarField.setAccessible(true);
    Object scrollBar = scrollBarField.get(mScrollCache);
    Method method = scrollBar.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setVerticalThumbDrawable", Drawable.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(scrollBar, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.scrollbar_style));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I haven't class Field, View.class, Object