# Color of ScrollBar in ScrollView

Tags: xamarin, scroll, xamarin.forms, scrollview, background-color

I use `Xamarin.Forms`, `ScrollView`, I can change `ScrollView.Background`, but background color of scroll bar don't change. How I can do it ? 
Can I make a universal shared style scrollbar for all platforms? 
If you can not, can I make so that I could use `ScrollView` in Shared project `Xamarin.forms` but at the same time that it is displayed at 
on different platforms with their own style? 
Maybe it can be done without their own styles and somehow easier? I need only custom scrollbar color in `ScrollView` `Xamarin.Forms`. 
I googled but found no examples of the using color of scrollbar `Xamarin.forms`. 
if it is not very easy to do, I would like to use an example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xamarin.Forms ScrollView control translates to a native scroll control on each platform. What you need to do, is create a custom [Effect](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/effects/introduction/) that gives you access to those underlying controls. From there you can customize the appearance of the scrollbar.

On Android, you need to work with [android.widget.ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html). You should define a custom drawable for the scrollbar in your resources folder and programmatically change the scrollbar to that inside your effect. There are quite a few answers on StackOverflow that show you how to do it, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781788/how-to-change-color-of-the-actual-scroll-in-scrollview-android?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806852/change-the-color-of-scrollview-programmatically).

On iOS, the native control is [UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview) from UIKit and the scrollbars are predefined images so you'll probably need to replace the image each time the control updates. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005187/ios-changing-uiscrollview-scrollbar-color-to-different-colors) for a good starting point.

In the end, you'll have something like this in your XAML:

```
<ScrollView>
    <ScrollView.Effects>
        <local:ScrollBarColorEffect ScrollBarColor="Green" />
    </ScrollView.Effects>
 ...
```