# How to set custom thumb in ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

I've tried to find out how to set scrollview thumb with a fixed height. 
Eventually, I did it by overriding ScrollView method, but I think it's not a good solution. Is there a more simple way of solving my issue.

The main problem was the thumb stretches depends on contents inside scrollview
I've set It's fixed size by overriding `computeVerticalScrollExtent` and recalculate offset in `computeVerticalScrollOffset`. 
Something like that

```
public class MyScrollView extends ScrollView {

    static final int CONST_THUMB = 100; // thumb height
    float divider = 1;

    public MyScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int computeVerticalScrollExtent() {

    int length = computeVerticalScrollRange() - 
                 super.computeVerticalScrollExtent();
    if(length > 0)
           divider = (float )(computeVerticalScrollRange() - 
                              CONST_THUMB)/(float )length;
    else
         return super.computeVerticalScrollExtent();

    return CONST_THUMB;
    }

    @Override
    public int computeVerticalScrollOffset() {
        return (int )((float )super.computeVerticalScrollOffset() * divider);
    }
}
```

It's set a fixed thumb height, and works for me, Is Android has a more effective solution? I need to have a thumb like a vertical SeekBar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set scrollbar thumb programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713909/how-to-set-scrollbar-thumb-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: Thanks, interesting way to change appearance of thumb but unfortunately height stretches