# Scrollbar color in NativeScript ScrollView

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, scrollview, scrollbar

Is there a way to change color of scrollbar in NativeScript ScrollView?

I looked into the API Reference of [ScrollView](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_scroll_view_.scrollview), but can not find any property that can change the color of scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the scrollbar's color is not supported, I don't think it's even possible in iOS. In Android it may be possible using native apis, you might want to check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19819843/1060423).

If you really want this, you might have to build your own component using touch events and adjust vertical / horizontal offset programatically.